# Overload resolution ambiguity for overloaded higher order function with function-type and generic input

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I have these two overloads for a higher order function:

```
// first function
fun<T> Response<T>.onSuccess(predicate: (T) -> Unit) {
    val body = body()
    if (isSuccessful && body != null) {
        predicate(body)
    }
}

// second function
fun<T> Response<T>.onSuccess(predicate: () -> Unit) {
    if (isSuccessful)
        predicate()
}
```

The first one has a function-type which takes a generic type argument and returns `Unit`. While the second function has a function-type that doesn't take any arguments.

The `Response` is the `retrofit2.Response` object which takes a generic type.

I can call the first function by explicitly naming the lamda parameter as follows:

```
response.onSuccess { result ->
    // not implemented
}
```

But the compiler gives a overload resolution ambiguity error when I try to call the second function:

```
response.onSuccess {    // error
    // not implemented
}
```

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
>
> public fun  Response<TypeVariable(T)>.onSuccess(predicate: () → Unit): Unit defined in com.vs.data.network in file NetworkHelper.kt
>
> public fun  Response<TypeVariable(T)>.onSuccess(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) →
> Unit): Unit defined in com.vs.data.network in file NetworkHelper.kt

Comment: Maybe because when lambda accepts one argument, the parameter is implicitly named it?

Comment: But the second function lamda doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: Yes, but the compiler does not understand which one you want to call: empty-parameter-list one or one-parameter-lambda with the parameter implicitly named it.

Comment: Yes I think that is the exact problem. But how to solve this?

Comment: { -> } worked for me to call 0-parameters-lambda.

Comment: This works for me too. But it raises an another question as what if the generic type in the first function has to be the lamda receiver and not be an argument.